# How to send this data to another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to send a string to another activity.

```
      long timeSpent = System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime;
      timeSpent = (long) (timeSpent / 1000.0);
   String string = "Game Over! Time spent " + String.valueOf(timeSpent) + "s";
```

I use this code, but it is wrong.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.putExtra("timespeent", timeSpent);
```

Comment: Please, make a small search by using Google before posting a question!

Comment: Pass the class in your Intent like this
Intent intent= new Intent(currentclass.this, NextClass.class);
intent.putExtra("timespent", string);
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you code like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.putExtra("timespeent", string);
```

Comment: Why? There's a method with a `long` parameter too: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, long) Depends on what *Gordon* needs.